# Openssl error 0x02001005 and 0x2006D002 on Windows?

Tags: windows, openssl

I'm trying to convert a .cer cert to a .p12 one using opensll.

this is the command that I'm using

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl x509 -inform der -in developer_identity.cer -out de
veloper_identity.pem
```

I'm conitunally getting an error and I don't know what it means. How can I figure out how to fix it.

```
2104:error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error:.\crypto\bio\bss_fil
e.c:163:fopen('C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin','rb')
2104:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c
:168:
2104:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system lib:.\crypto\con
f\conf_def.c:199:
```

**EDIT 1**

I'm not entirely sure if I'm using it correctly so I'll outline what I tried.

1) Downloaded openssl.exe and installed it.

2) Copied the cert file I want to work with to the bin folder in the install location.

3) Entered the command at the top of this post

Comment: It looks like it's falling over trying to open a directory as the "config file", although I didn't think x509 *needed* any config. Can you specify an alternate config file by setting the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin
```

Looks like it's trying to open a directory for reading? Does openssl work generally or is there some problem with its installation?

Comment: this is the first time I've ever tried to use it. This it where I got the exe from .http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: What does "openssl version -a" do? Give an error, or print the version? Which version did you download, and what's your operating system? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I tried downloading a version other than the "lite" version and it seems to have worked. Thanks for giving me the idea

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I resolved with the above answer.

Just type depending on 32 o 64 bits:

C:> set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg

or

C:> set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg

Thanks.

Comment: Installing to a custom directory effects this, so in example at the command prompt in the `C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\OpenSSL x64\bin` directory I typed `set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\OpenSSL x64\bin\openssl.cfg` based on your answer. Hopefully this should clarify for anyone else, thanks for your post.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an open issue for you or not, but I just solved this for myself.

From a Windows command prompt:

```
C:\> set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding argument:

```
-config <full_path_to_the_openssl_config_file>
```

for example:

```
-config c:\OpenSSL-Win3\bin\openssl.cfg
```

so your command looks like this:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in developer_identity.cer -out developer_identity.pem -config c:\OpenSSL-Win3\bin\openssl.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why everyone suggests changing your Environment Variables. For me, it was already set. Perhaps the older versions didn't? I guess double check it's set right. Either way, I was unable to use openssl at all. Restarting Windows after installation solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving the openssl directory to the root of C: drive and setting the env variable.