# Cannot generate Certificate Signing Request in XAMPP

Tags: ssl, openssl, xampp, csr

I tried to follow this guide

https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR198

Basically

`C:\xampp\php\extras\openssl>openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048`

Then

`C:\xampp\apache\bin>openssl req -new -key private.key -config "C:\xampp\php\extr
as\openssl" -out request.csr`

I got error:

```
error on line -1 of C:\xampp\php\extras\openssl
4456:error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error:.\crypto\bio\bss_fil
e.c:126:fopen('C:\xampp\php\extras\openssl','rb')
4456:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c
:131:
4456:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system lib:.\crypto\con
f\conf_def.c:199:
```

Here are my system info

```
Windows NT LGLAC046 6.1 build 7600 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition) i586 

Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 

OPENSSL_CONF    C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf 

SSL Version     OpenSSL/0.9.8y
```

What is this error and how to generate CSR?

Comment: as the error says, you don't have an openssl.cnf file...

Comment: Ops I copied the wrong error. Fixed now

Comment: `set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\xampp\php\extras\openssl\bin\openssl.cfg` from [what does this openssl error mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106035/what-does-this-openssl-error-mean). It sounds about right due to the changes in Windows paths.

Comment: @jww, your trick works. You can answer below and I mark approval